# How do I know what version the Mini DisplayPort port is on my 2010 MacBook Pro?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, displayport

I want to connect 2 monitors to my MacBook Pro (mid-2010). The problem is that I don't if the Mini DisplayPort is version 1.2, which would support daisy chaining.  How can I figure out what version firmware my Mini DisplayPort uses and whether or not it would support daisy chaining?

Comment: Similar: [*Identify what version of DisplayPort supported on the Thunderbolt port*](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/257339/17907)

Answer (score 2):

Thanks so much for your post above - it really places a relatively simple way for all of us to trace our CPU, then GPU and from there the manufacturer stated max resolutions.

Thanks to your clear post, I cld trace my MacBook Pro 13" 2017's Intel i5 to it's Intel Iris Plus roots...and there it's stated (what no one else has told me):
The manufacturer of the Iris 640 says it will only support:

- HDMI up to an upper limit of 4K 30Hz.
- Native DisplayPort can support up to 4K 60Hz and
- eDP (for internal display) will also do 4K60Hz.

Huge puzzle solved...explains why so many hv failed by the HDMI wayside. And the few who hv succeeded used a direct wire i.e. thunderbolt3/USB-C to DisplayPort cable thereby gaining native DisplayPort and then the hallowed 4K60Hz!

Thanks for yr time in the pre-dawn hours! You've saved me time in the darkest ones!!
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

The 2011 MBP (MacBookPro8,1) has thunderbolt, so either your machine is not a 2011, or it has thunderbolt. the 2010 MacBook Pros have MDP that supports audio as well as video (I have a 2009 which only does video).

Keep in mind that MDP and Thunderbolt look identical.

Comment: Good call.  It says mid-2010.

Answer (score 1):

Open System Information, then under Hardware select Mini DisplayPort. This will tell you about the firmware of the port controller and more.

Comment: Oddly enough, Mini DisplayPort is not listed there.

Comment: @Bradford Is there anything else that would be close? DisplayPort, display, etc?

Comment: "Thunderbolt", but when you click on it it says "No hardware was found."  Under Graphics/Displays I see my video cards.  But nothing on them that mentions DisplayPort.

Comment: There are no Mini DisplayPort ports on newer Macs. On a Mac mini (2018) running macOS Mojave, no version of DisplayPort is listed under `System Information` > `Hardware` > `Graphics/Displays` nor `Thunderbolt`.

Answer (score 1):

This FAQ from Apple: http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3382#5

Key part:

> 6 Can other video adapters be connected or "daisy-chained" to Apple Mini DisplayPort adapters?
>
> No, you should not connect Apple Mini DisplayPort adapters to any
>   other video adapters. Connect your computer directly to an external
>   display via one Mini DisplayPort adapter.

So, regardless of the version, I'd be cautious.

Comment: The Apple article is referring to multiple cables or adapters. The question is about connecting multiple *monitors* where the first monitor has an output that can be connected to the second monitor's input, as per http://www.displayport.org/cables/driving-multiple-displays-from-a-single-displayport-output/

Answer (score 1):

So I looked up this question, it's 4 in the morning here in California, 2 years later...

I hope this answer finds you or anyone else interested because I think I backtracked a solid answer for both of us.

I have lately been getting into doing some specific display work and came across this question, how far can I really push my Macbook Pro 13 with 512mb GPU. It's all based on the video card, as I connected the dots to my experience with audio and sound.

Here's what I've found...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort

Which like you, led me to the same place, my Mac's about info/system report/graphics and displays and then... nothing. There were some clues though...

The intel 3000 graphics chipset

http://intel.ly/2enZo7q

I did some more research via Apple on my chipset and found this, it dates my computer very very well, check this out...

http://apple.co/2ePaukk

So for me I was a 3000 ok? something like 2011... then do this... it's like a complex math problem right? If you know the date of your computer, what connection you have (definitely, mini display port(WHICH ONLY SUPPORT SOME FORM OF HDMI)) but just need to know what kind of HDMI...drum roll please... then all you need to know is the date of your HDMI technology...

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HDMI#Version_1.4)

The new technology including '4k' (1.4) was out 2009

At that point my only option is to assume that my late 2011 macbook includes the previous HDMI 1.4 technology.

I've compared the numbers between Mini DisplayPort 1.2 and HDMI 1.4 and they are aligned. Now you know you have and Mini DisplayPort 1.2 that can push 4k @ 24hz

Peace in the universe has been restored :)

It's something like 4:15 now and I'm glad I found this. I hope this post finds you or helps person waking up from a deep sleep needing to know their max computer resolution. Share this with your friends, add me on the socials, good luck and may the force be with you ;)

Cheers,

C

other sites

[en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface))

[www.displayport.org/](http://www.displayport.org/)