# Identify what version of DisplayPort supported on the Thunderbolt port

Tags: hardware, thunderbolt, displayport

How do I tell what version of [DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort) is support on a Mac’s [Thunderbolt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thunderbolt_(interface)) port, when running macOS El Capitan or Sierra?

I tried using the [*System Information*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_Information_(Mac)) app.

- No item listed for “DisplayPort”.
- The “Graphics/Displays” item lists video cards.
- The “Thunderbolt” item has no information about DisplayPort.

My Samsung 4K monitor has an switch setting for either [DisplayPort 1.1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.0_to_1.1) or [1.2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#1.2). So I'd like to match appropriately to my MacBook Pro.

Apple does not document this important information. For example, this Apple Support page, [*Mac mini (2018) - Technical Specifications*](https://support.apple.com/kb/SP782?viewlocale=en_US&locale=en_US) says only:

> Thunderbolt 3 digital video output supports
>   Native DisplayPort output over USB-C
>
> Four Thunderbolt 3 (USB-C) ports with support for:
>   DisplayPort

…with no mention of which [version of DisplayPort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DisplayPort#Versions) standard.

---

[This Question](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/142405/17907) seemed to be asking this question. But it is not exactly clear. And no Answer directly addressed the issue.

Comment: What model Mac are you running? And what macOS?

Comment: @Monomeeth Answered (El Capitan or Sierra). As for which Mac model, I am looking for an answer that works across various Macs; I am asking how to look up the version of DisplayPort supported in general, not for this one specific Mac.

Comment: Based on https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mini_DisplayPort, it sounds like if the output does not support 4k, it's 1.1, and if it does, it's 1.2.  Not an Apple reference, I know.

Comment: You said, "So I'd like to match appropriately to my MacBook Pro.", so what version is your MacBook Pro?

Comment: @user3439894 MacBook Pro (late 2013) with discrete GPU card. But the Question is more general than than one specific model.

Comment: At the time of the release of the MacBook Pro (late 2013) it would have at best supported 1.2a. I know you said you want it in general; however, IMO that makes the question too broad and subject to closure.